# Python- Find type of the variable using the type object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an object which is similar to the pandas dataframe and on calling its `data_type()` method it returns a dictionary of data types for each column.

```
dtypes = df.data_type()
dtypes
# {'Unnamed: 0': <class 'int'>, '0': <class 'str'>, '1': <class 'float'>, '2': <class 'float'>, '3': <class 'float'>, '4': <class 'float'>, '5': <class 'float'>, '6': <class 'float'>, '7': <class 'float'>, '8': <class 'float'>, '9': <class 'float'>, '10': <class 'float'>, '11': <class 'float'>, '12': <class 'float'>, '13': <class 'str'>, '14': <class 'str'>}
```

As you can see, the type of dictionary values returned here is `type`.

Now, I need to perform some operations which are specific to the string/character columns and hence want to select the columns with that are `<class 'str'>`. The problem is that I can't use `isinstance` here because `<class 'str'>` is of type `<class 'type'>` and all my comparisons are returning `False` and hence none of the columns are getting selected.

So the question here is how do I use the output of a `type` function to compare with python data types(int, float, str)?

Comment: why the downvote? If there's an already existing answer, please share the link. If there's any other issue with the question, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following specifically to the string/character columns

```
for col in df.columns:
    if(df[col].dtype == np.float64 or df[col].dtype == np.int64):
         ##do something
    else:
          #do for string
```

Comment: This won't work. I am not using pandas dataframe. I have an object that borrows from pandas and uses custom methods.